# Min being ignored in <input> tag

Tags: html, knockout.js

Ok so I don't know the first thing about knockout.js and that may be my issue.
I am maintaining an ASP.NET application and I was tasked with changing an html
file in the solution that uses knockout.js. Here is the line of code that is having an issue:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Quantity, uniqueId: Quantity, uniqueMod: 'measure-quantity', enable: IsNotListMeasureIndividually() && !IsNotInstalled()" />
```

This input tag is allowing the user to enter a negative number and we dont want to allow that. So what I tried was to add min="1" to the tag. The result was it got ignored then moved on to the next set of lines of code
then blew up.

Is the reason that the min is not working because this is not just a simple input tag and includes knockout references in the data-bind? 
If so, how can I go about putting in the desired validation to 
only accept positive numbers? Please help and remember I know nothing about knockout. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this. Use javascript to ignore the keypress of the negative symbol. I don't think that all browsers support the number type Of course you will need the correct handle to assign the keydown event to the right input box.

```
document.getElementByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
      if ( event.which == 109 || event.which == 173 ) {
          event.preventDefault();
      }
 });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cmmqdph/2/)

This combined with the min="0" attribute will prevent the number block from allowing negative numbers.